# Что значит двоеточие в sql запросе?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Первый раз с таким столкнулся в java коде не получается нагуглить. Похоже на переменную..

```
"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table t WHERE t.goal_id = :goalId";
```

База постгре.

Comment: [Using Host Variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ecpg-variables.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это значит, что в это место будет подставлено значение в ваш SQL запрос из вашего Java кода.

Например, у класса `MapSqlParameterSource` есть метод `addValue(String paramName, @Nullable Object value)`, где `paramName` - указываете `goalId`, а в `value` - значение, которое хотите подставить.

Comment: Слегка запутался. У нас в запросе есть одна переменная для подстановки goalId. В методе addValue мы подставляем value, а paramName зачем?

Comment: Скорей всего речь вы ведете о `addValues(@Nullable Map<String, ?> values)`? Ну то есть тут должно быть понятно, что вы передаете сразу коллекцию пар `Имя параметра - Связываемое значение`. Если откроете посмотреть реализацию `MapSqlParameterSource`, тогда все поймете.

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие значит переменная связывания